# Mac os 10.8.2 Ros Fuerte, tutorial "CMake with rosserial_arduino" problem

Tags: arduino, rosserial, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Was following http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/CMake tutorial on ros website, "cmake ." command finished and then when i ran "make chatter" command, got these errors:

avr-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch'
avr-g++: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/chatter.dir/src/chatter.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/chatter.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/chatter.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [chatter] Error 2

I think it has something to do with CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS flags, wonder if there is any way to remove "-arch x86_64" flag.

Additional info:

$ which avr-g++
/usr/local/bin/avr-g++
$ avr-g++ --version
avr-g++ (GCC) 4.7.0

$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44799/mac-os-10.8.2-ros-fuerte,-tutorial-%22cmake-with-rosserial_arduino%22-problem/) by [Darius](https://answers.ros.org/users/3283/darius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Managed to change it manually, by editing CMakeFiles/chatter.dir/flags.make file, but then got stuck with another problem :) "fatal error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory" well at least my arduino ide works with ros..

---

Originally posted by [Darius](https://answers.ros.org/users/3283/darius/) with karma: 16 on 2012-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0